# Calculating this integral along a Bezier curve in code

Tags: integration, programming, bezier-curve

I'm doing some graphics code work and need to solve this integral in code:

$$
\int_{0}^{1} f(P(t)) dt
$$

Where $P(t)$ is a quadratic or cubic Bezier curve, and $f(p)$ ($p$ is a point) is defined as:

$$
f(p) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } 0 \le p_x \le 1, & 0 \le p_y \le 1  \\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

So we're taking an integral along the path of the Bezier curve, but only within the square region $0 \le p_x \le 1, \text{ } 0 \le p_y \le 1$, since $f(p)$ is $0$ everywhere else. The code that needs to compute this can make no assumptions about the input Bezier curves.

I understand that what we're doing is basically "clipping" the curve to a square region, and we need to find the range of the parameter $t$ where the curve lies within that region (taking into account the case where the curve lies completely outside the region). But I cannot figure out a generalised way to solve this. If I can look at the curve visually then it becomes clear how to find the required range of $t$, but I cannot understand a general technique that can be implemented in code.

Comment: You can rewrite the integral as $\int_{0}^{1} f(P(t)) \cdot \mathbb{1}\{P(t) \in \Omega\} \ \mathrm{d}t$ where $\Omega$ is your region of interest, which in this case is a square. You have a new integrand and now implement the integration over this. $\mathbb{1}(A)$ denotes the indicator of the event $A$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Could you elaborate a bit more since I don't think I have encountered integration that looks like that. I don't quite get the $1(A)$ notation you've used

Comment: $\mathbb{1}(A)$ is the indicator variable and takes the value 1 whenever A is true or the event A occurs and 0 otherwise. So when you multiply this with f, you will note that is 1 only when the points are inside the square and it makes the integrand 0 in all other cases. So you do not need to worry about evaluating the ranges of $t$ in this case.

Comment: As an example, you evaluate the integral by summing it over the points $[0,0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]$ and $P(t)$ is within the square for $t \in [0.18, 0.41]$. Then corresponding vector for function will look like $[f(0), f(0.2), f(0.4), f(0.6), f(0.8), f(1)]$ and that of the indicators will look like $[0,1,1,0,0,0]$. On multiplying them, you will have $[0,f(0.2), f(0.4), 0,0,0]$, which on adding gives the required result. In this case, you never had to find the interval $[0.18, 0.41]$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 I looked into indicator functions and understood what they are now, but I'm still not sure how that would help in evaluating the integral. The only input is the control points of the Bezier curve, I don't have a list of points to sum over. So, only given the control points, how would the integration look like using the indicator variable?

Comment: As far as I understand, given the control points, you have the Beizer curve $P(t)$ by varying the parameter $t$. So when you integrate along the Beizer curve, you are likely going to use some numerical integration technique, say Riemann integration for simplicity. In that case, you will evaluate the function at uniformly spaced points, take their sum and multiply by interval width. Now if you multiple the indicator function with each of the evaluated values, points outside square will evaluate to 0 and not count in the integral, giving you desired sum. Does that help?

Comment: I was trying to stick to an analytic solution but I'll give numerical methods a shot, that does help yes thanks

Comment: @sudeep5221 I noticed an issue, because $f(p)$ has such a small support, then as the length of the curve increases, I would need more subdivisions in the Riemann integration to get accurate results, whereas I need a constant number of subdivisions. Any ideas on how I could handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Approximate the Bézier curve $P(t)$ by a polyline $L(t)$. Clipping the polyline to the square is easy. You will find several intervals, $[a,b]$ where $L(t)$ is inside the square for $t \in [a,b]$. Add up the lengths of these intervals.

You didn’t say anything about the degree of your Bézier curves. If they are always cubic, you can do the clipping directly, without the polyline approximation. Look up “Bézier clipping”.

Comment: I mentioned that I'll be working with only quadratic or cubic Bezier curves. I did come across Bezier clipping, I'll look into it more

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. Then you can intersect the curve with the sides of the square just by solving quadratic or cubic equations. Then, again, you just add up the lengths of the intervals $[a,b]$ corresponding to portions of the curve that are inside the square.

Comment: I considered that, and yeah, I can solve 4 quadratic or cubic equations to get intersection points, but that does not tell me which regions are inside and which are outside. For example a quadratic Bezier curve could intersect a line at two parameters $t_1$ and $t_2$, but depending on the orientation of the curve I would either have to take the region $[t_1, t_2]$ or the sum of the regions $[0, t_1]$ and $[t_2, 1]$

Comment: So, calculate points on the curve at $\tfrac12t_1$, $\tfrac12(t_1+t_2)$ and $\tfrac12(t_2+1)$, and check which of these points are inside the square. That will tell you which segments are inside.